# RecyclerView messing with its child's customview Touch event

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have an GraphView (Custom view) which needs to supports horizontal scrolling.
This graphView is a child item of Recyclerviews (as a separate Viewholder/Viewtype). 
My Recyclerview supports Vertical scrolling.

Layout Hierarchy

- RecyclerView

  - Item type 1
  - Item type 2
  - Item type 3

    - FrameLayout

      - GraphView
  - Item type 4

The problem is, when I swipe horizontally on GraphView, my entire RecyclerView goes up and down (sometimes GraphView scrolls also)

GraphView's GestureDetector:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    boolean retVal = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return retVal || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener
        = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        releaseEdgeEffects();
        mScrollerStartViewport.set(mCurrentViewport);
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(GenericGraph.this);
        Log.i("ashwin", "Graphs | onDown()");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // Snap touch point to closest data value.
        if (pixelToChartConversion(e.getX(), e.getY(), mDestPointF)) {
            Point p = getClosestDataPoint(new Float(mDestPointF.x).longValue());
            if (p != null) {
                mFinalTouchPointX = getDrawX(p.getX().getTime());
                mValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mCurrentTouchPointX, mFinalTouchPointX);
                mValueAnimator.setDuration(Constants.Misc.GRAPH_ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
                mValueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                mValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        mCurrentTouchPointX = ((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue()).floatValue();
                        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(GenericGraph.this);
                    }
                });
                mValueAnimator.start();
            }
        }

        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(GenericGraph.this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        scroll(distanceX, -distanceY, true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        fling((int) -velocityX, (int) -velocityY);
        return true;
    }
};
```

One strange behavior I found is, if I used the GraphView inside any VerticalScroll view then the scrolling work perfectly fine on graphview.
The problem only occurs with the RecyclerView.

Any suggestions/ help is really appreciated.

Comment: Probably the view will need some setInterceptTouchEvent(true) the RecyclerView will not give scroll to childs for free

Comment: Not sure, but I think that HorizontalScrollView can be a child of RecyclerView, check its source code how it handle the events

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have followed Recyclerview.LayoutManager class touch handling implementation and resolved the issue.

Comment: @AshwinKhadgi can you post your solution?